# Test connection to postgres with SSL with the command line

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I need to test a connection to a distant postgres database with SSL turned on, and be notified of the result.
I have the following command:

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=myRootCert.crt sslcert=myPublicCert.crt sslkey=myPrivateKey.key hostaddr=host user=user port=port dbname=db password=passwd"
```

It works fine, I am logged in and I can start typing commands.
But what I need is only the status of the connection test, I don't want to be logged in after.

I saw there is a `pg_isready` command, but I can not find how to use it with SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your connection string like this:

```sh
pg_isready -d 'sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=myRootCert.crt sslcert=myPublicCert.crt sslkey=myPrivateKey.key hostaddr=host user=user port=port dbname=db password=passwd'
```